# CheckBoxes not staying checked after leaving the activity and returning to it

Tags: android, checkbox

I am putting together a very basic Android app in which the user defines some preferences using CheckBoxes. I have a set of CheckBoxes which I therefore want to stay checked or unchecked (depending on how the user interacts with them) if the user moves to a previous activity, or for that matter even if the user closes the app and then reopens it. I'm not sure how to go about doing this, any help? I would imagine there are certain methods to use to save the state of the CheckBoxes, but I am not sure what they would be or how to use them.

Comment: Use sharedPreferences to save the state of your checkboxes.

Comment: Can you provide us your code? You might be destroying (finish()) it. In this case, the activity is recreated.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options (from easiest to the hardest)

1. Use Shared Preferences
2. Save your settings to the file system as a .xml file
3. Save your settings to the local SQLite database