# CheckBoxes Not Being Saved

Tags: android, checkbox

[CheckBoxes not staying checked after leaving the activity and returning to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290706/checkboxes-not-staying-checked-after-leaving-the-activity-and-returning-to-it)
I have already visited this webpage and have a similar question.But still dont know the answer. This is the activity with checkboxes which I have ticked.

[image]

[image: enter image [![description] In the second image I went back to the previous activity.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H38Ab.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H38Ab.png)

[![Now I went back to the original activity and the checkboxes arent ticked.
Please help me.
 Thanks
Kalyan][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqkVF.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kqkVF.png)

EDIT: The view in the screenshots is 'android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice'

Comment: Um the layout is multiple_checked-Item

Comment: please the add the code....to the question

Comment: I can tell that he has used an ArrayAdapter to make the ListView
This would probably be the code
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, listToDisplay);